# How to load images from Dropbox using Picasso

Tags: java, android, dropbox, picasso

I'm trying to load a image from Dropbox withou any success, but I searched that I need to download the image first but, the image seems to be a Thumbnail. I tried using the DropBox API but it requieres the API key and I just want to download the image. Theres any efective way to do this ?

The last thing that I tried was this :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

It works with normal images but not Thumbnails!

Answer (score 0):

You need the Dropbox URL (shared) for the image.

Follow the below steps -

1. Add the below dependency in build.gradle (module) file.

   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'
2. Sync your project
3. Store the dropbox URL in a variable -

   String dropBoxURL = "(your Dropbox URL)";
4. Use that URL in Picasso like this -

   Picasso.get().load("" + dropBoxURL).into(Your display class);

That is all.

Comment: As I said, It doesn't work with Picasso, any Image URI works but not with Dropbox.